# Counting how many rows a group consist of?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am working with an Excel sheet where some rows has been `grouped`. It's also called `outline`. It's when rows are selected, and made into a collapsable group, like shown [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-08ce98c4-0063-4d42-8ac7-8278c49e9aff). I'd like to use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and search for those groups, and if possible - tell me how many rows each of the groups consists of.

Example:
`A1:A5` is a group of 5 rows, and `A6:A16` is group of 11 rows.

I was thinking I could maybe iterate through column `A` and somehow look for `.row_dimensions.group`, since this is the method used to create such a group using openpyxl.
If it matters, the `outline_level = 1` in each group.

Comment: I've never heard of openpyxl - have you considered using `pandas` for this task?

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
But sure, I could try `pandas` if that can help me with the task.